# Quantum ripple-carry adder construction

Tags: ibm-q-experience, circuit-construction, quantum-circuit

[image: quantum RCA]

I am attempting to build a 2-bit ripple-carry adder, using IBM Quantum Experience composer, but I'm confused on how to construct the carry transpose that is shown at the bottom?

Answer (score 1):

The $\dagger$ means inverse. Invert the individual operations within $C$ (they are all self-inverse so this is easy) and then run them in reverse order.

Comment: can I remove it since it does nothing in this case? and do you mean that if I want to implement it then the toffeli gate would be at the end of the carry?

Comment: @n22 No you can't remove it. Each operation of $C$ is self-inverse, but you still need to run them in reverse order.